# Regex error when handling with tags

Tags: regex

I am trying to convert this:

```
[img,src=http://www.ANYTHINGHERE.com/image.png,width=55px,height=105px]<br />
```

To this:

```
<img src="http://www.ANYTHINGHERE.com/image.png" width=55px height=105px>
```

(without spaces)
I am trying with this regex:

```
/(\[img[| |,|]?[(src=(.*)?)|(width=(.*)?)|(height=(.*)?)|,]*)(\])/<br />
```

But it doesn't find the tag

Comment: Which programming language are you working with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex without escaping:

```
[([a-z]+?),([a-z]+?)=([^,]+),([a-z]+?)=([^,]+),([a-z]+?)=([^,]+)]
```

and replace in pseudocode:

```
<$1 $2="$3" $4="$5" $6="$7">
```

Answer (score 1):

I might add there are lots of resources to test regex, like this [Regex Tester](http://www.regextester.com/), which gives you real time feedback to how your regex is matching.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to escape a lot of those characters.

EDIT: Now looking at your actual regex, the problem is the character class in the middle. You realize character classes are only for alternations of individual characters, right?

Comment: So how can I do that for a lot of characters?